# tomcat 8 jsp javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I dont understand this error 500 and cookie problem, hoping someone can inlight me.

When i run my requestDispatcher i get an internal erro 500 that i cant figure out. The ressource is /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp but in the error message it says /WEB-INF/jsp/cookie???

The error message

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The
>   requested resource
>   (/MyNewRandomBlog1.0/WEB-INF/jsp/{cookie=JSESSIONID=4724BBA140EA29EFF07AD782C755ED13,
>   cache-control=no-cache, connection=Keep-Alive, host=localhost:8080,
>   accept-language=da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3, accept=image/jpeg,
>   application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml,
>   image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel,
>   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*,
>   user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64;
>   x64; Trident/7.0; ASU2JS), accept-encoding=gzip, deflate,
>   ua-cpu=AMD64}) is not available

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyNewRandomBlog1.0</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>frontpage</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>dk.danicait.servlets.FrontpageCreation</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>intname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frontpage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My file tree

[image]

Also i dont use any cookies in my program, so the cookie it displays in the message is a standard cookie?

Just to make sure that the file for the requestDispatcher **really** exist i did

```
String test = sc.getResource("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").toString();
```

Which works fine getting the ressource url.

Edit. Added servlet code

```
public class FrontpageCreation extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

//      Set request attributes
        request.setAttribute("header", sc.getResource("/includes/nav.jsp").toString());
        request.setAttribute("footer", sc.getResource("/includes/footer.jsp").toString());

//      Request dispatcher
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are defining your serlvet as `intname` mapped to `/frontpage` so try invoking it as `http://<server>:<port>/MyNewRandomBlog1.0/frontpage` - btw all resources inside `WEB-INF` are protected and not accessible directly from  outside of the web app (i.e. from a user's browser)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ochi. As i understand frontpage in welcome file, /forntpage and intname are all internal values that can be what we desire. Also i use this style in other projects with no issues.

I placed the .jsp files in the WEB-INF file, so i can enforce a servlet call first that will in turn generate the index.jsp and all other .jsp pages. So dynamic content can be inserted to the pages and users cant directly browse them.

When i call the http://localhost:8080/MyNewRandomBlog1.0/frontpage i get the error.

Comment: Can you share some code from the  `FrontpageCreation` servlet then?

Comment: Shared the servlet code in the original question at the end.

Comment: try changing the path for `header` and `footer` to include a `.` (dot) in front - as in, `./includes/nav.jsp` - OR try removing those two attributes first and see if a simplified `index.jsp` (with a plain hello world message) is being served to the browser properly

Comment: @ochi the `.` will make it angry as the path has to start with a `/` but definitely should try serving a simply `index.jsp` before adding any additional complexity.  That's where I would start at least anyway.

Comment: Okey so i found out where the problem resides. In my index.jsp page i try and take the url value of the header and footer pages and include them in the index.page with <c:import url="${header}"/> And that is causing the problem, because the url import statement doesnt understand the formatting i suspect? But what would than be the correct way to pass the url from the servlet to the index.jsp page and import the pages?

Comment: Nice!, See my answer... looks like you JSP file does not import the JSTL tag library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in

```
request.setAttribute("header", sc.getResource("/includes/nav.jsp").toString());
request.setAttribute("footer", sc.getResource("/includes/footer.jsp").toString());
```

Where i try and pass these values to

```
<c:import url="${header}"/>
<c:import url="${footer}"/>
```

in the index.jsp page, where i believe the import statement does not understand the formatting of the values passed. And theirby gives a error 500 message.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are importing the JSTL libraries in your JSP before using them

i.e. add this at the top of your `index.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

before calling this line:

```
<c:import url="${header}"/>
```

Comment: I have this at the top of my document on the second line <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> and the .jar files javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar in /WEB-INF/lib/ But i still get the error with the import statement

Comment: you have an extra semi-colon (`;`) in your import statement - remove it