# tomcat 8 jsp how to include / import a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to include / import a header and a footer in my project from my servlet, but so far i havent managed to do so.

What i have tried

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

//      Set request attributes
        request.setAttribute("header", sc.getResource("/includes/nav.jsp").toString());
        request.setAttribute("footer", sc.getResource("/includes/footer.jsp").toString());


//      Request dispatcher
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Pass it to my index.jsp and than extract the paths

```
<c:import url="${header}"/>
<c:import url="${footer}"/>
```

But this does not work and give an internal 500 error.

[tomcat 8 jsp javax.servlet.ServletException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015734/tomcat-8-jsp-javax-servlet-servletexception)

I have also tried

```
sc.getRealPath("/includes/nav.jsp");
sc.getRealPath("/includes/footer.jsp");
```

But didnt work

What is the correct way to archive this.
Is it passing a different value the import statement understand, if so how should i format it?
Or should i use another method for archiving the import of the pages?

The file tree

[image]

Comment: Can you show your file tree and full stacktrace?

Comment: I have added the file tree, im not sure what you mean with a full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

file:/C:/Use ... etc is not the right way to write it.

would the relative path be "includes/footer.jsp"?

```
<jsp:include page=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+'includes/footer.jsp' />;
```

Comment: The result of the getRessource method returns a path file:/C/...... If i placed the .war file on my local tomcat server it would say /opt/tomcat.... I use the relative path of "/includes/nav.jsp" This works fine with <img> elements, but so far no luck with .jsp pages.